# How to seperate histogram plot into two facet with ggplot in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet

I want to separate my histogram into two parts and zoom the second part. In short, I want to keep the histogram in the original shape, just zoom the x-axis tail.
Using mpg dataset as an example, I create a facet label according to 'displ' column and create a histogram plot.

```
mpg$displn<-scale(mpg$displ)
mpg$myFacet<-"01"
mpg$myFacet[mpg$displn>1]<-"02"
library(ggh4x)
ggplot(mpg,aes(x=displn))+geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),binwidth = 0.1)+ facet_grid(. ~ myFacet, scales="free", space="free") + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-1.5, 2.5, 1)) + theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())+ theme(panel.spacing=unit(0,'npc')) +force_panelsizes(cols = c(0.3, 1))
```

The question is the two facets using different 'y=..density..' and looks different from the original figure.
Is there any suggestion on how should I improve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Typically, one would use `ggforce::facet_zoom()` for this purpose:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = scale(displ))) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)), binwidth = 0.1) +
  facet_zoom(xlim = c(1, 3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The reason your original approach doesn't work is because densities are calculated by group, and data belonging to different panels are automatically separated into different groups.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is I do not want to show a separate zoom plot, only want an "unequal" x-axis... I also tried to use xlim() to separate the histogram into three parts then merged with ggarrange, but the main figure size differs if I want to hide the y axis....

Comment: Instead of calculating the density automatically, you can also calculate the density manually by using `aes(y= after_stat(count / nrow(mpg)))`. This should get rid of the group-wise densities and retain total density.